# Resultado SQL en PHP como String

Tags: php, sql, array

Estoy intentando poner el resultado de una consulta SQL en un string, concatenando los resultados.

```
 $poblaciones = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT poblacion FROM wp_custom_poblacion
    WHERE postal = (SELECT cod_postal FROM WPCalidad.wp_custom_proveedores ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);');
```

Esto me devolverá una lista con varias ciudades, las cuales quiero poner enun string.
Sé que debe ser algo sencillo, pero no lo consigo. Poniéndolo así funciona:

```
$municipio=$poblaciones[0]->poblacion . $poblaciones[1]->poblacion ;
```

y con un for tb, pero solamente si pongo $tamano=5, por ejemplo.

```
for ($i=0;$i<$tamano;$i++){
$municipio=  $municipio .  $poblaciones[$i]->poblacion. "; " ;
```

}

¿Cómo puedo sacar en $tamano el tamaño del array? He probado count, mysql_num_rows...pero algo estaré haciendo mal que no funciona.

Gracias!

---

```
while($elem = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT poblacion FROM wp_custom_poblacion WHERE postal = (SELECT cod_postal FROM WPCalidad.wp_custom_proveedores ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);')) {

  $municipio = $municipio. $elem . "; ";
}
```

Así no me funciona.

---

Nada, que no hay manera. He probado mil cosas y o me rellena la cadena en blanco, o me pone Array Array Array...... Así lo tengo ahora.

```
    global $wpdb;


    // Para proveedores
    $datosproveedor = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT  wp_custom_proveedores.id,
wp_custom_poblacion.provincia 
FROM wp_custom_poblacion
INNER JOIN wp_custom_proveedores on wp_custom_proveedores.cod_postal=wp_custom_poblacion.postal
WHERE wp_custom_poblacion.pais=(SELECT pais FROM WPCalidad.wp_custom_proveedores ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;');

    $poblacionesproveedor = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT poblacion FROM wp_custom_poblacion
        WHERE postal = (SELECT cod_postal FROM WPCalidad.wp_custom_proveedores ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);');

    $tamanoproveedor = 5;
   /* for ($i = 0; $i < $tamanoproveedor; $i++) {

        $municipioproveedor = $municipioproveedor . $poblacionesproveedor[$i]->poblacion . "; ";

    }*/

    foreach ($poblacionesproveedor as $poblacion){
  $municipioproveedor = $municipioproveedor . $poblacionesproveedor->$poblacion;
}
```

Si yo lo único que quiero es que $municipioproveedor contenga la lista de las poblaciones...:(

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a utilizar un bucle foreach

```
foreach ($poblaciones as $poblacion){
  print_r($poblaciones);
}
```

en caso de necesitar acceder al indice del array puedes usar `$index -> $poblacion`